# HTML one page to another page

Tags: php, html

I had created two HTML pages. In one page I will take input from the user through filling the form and in second form I will put all Details with some nice CSS stuffs.

So How do I transfer my first page variables to my other web pages ?

Thank You.

Comment: `POST/GET/SESSION`, plenty of fish in the sea. Where is your code?

Comment: Atleast Paste your code which you tried.

Comment: Suppose I have 10 field in form to fill, So I can transfer all 10 variable in other pages by just using get or post ? (Can you give me Example plz - short example)

Comment: @BBD. ofcourse you can. Is there anything that you've tried yet? A simple HTML page with 10 fields, perhaps?

Comment: Suppose you post some or all of your relevant code or markup?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Yes I have tried

Comment: @BBD. Kindly add that code in your question.

Comment: How to add HTML code ? when I had past it, its shows me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a plenty of ways to achieve what you've mentioned. Some of them:

**Using POST:**

`Where the method = "POST"`

```
 <form action="nextpage.php" method="POST">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Address: <input type="text" name="add"><br>
  Address 2: <input type="text" name="add2"><br>
  <input type="submit"name = "sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then on `nextpage.php`:

Which is defined in `action = "nextpage.php"`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
echo $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
echo $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
echo $add = $_POST['add'];
echo $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
?>
}
```

**Using GET:**

`Where the method = "GET"`

```
 <form action="nextpage.php" method="GET">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Address: <input type="text" name="add"><br>
  Address 2: <input type="text" name="add2"><br>
  <input type="submit"name = "sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then on `nextpage.php`:

Which is defined in `action = "nextpage.php"`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sub'])){
echo $first_name = $_GET['fname'];
echo $last_name = $_GET['lname'];
echo $add = $_GET['add'];
echo $add2 = $_GET['add2'];
?>
}
```

**EDIT:**

Moving forward from the link you posted under this answer as a comment. You have missing attributes in your `<form>` tag. i.e. No `method` or `action` defined. Further more, put a `<input type = "submit" ../>` before closing your `</form>` rather than a `<button>` afterward.

**Fix:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Resume Generator </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <form method = "POST" action = "nextpage.php">

            <label for = "Applicant_Name"> Full Name : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "fullname" required autofocus>  <br> </br>

            <label for = "contact_no"> Contact No. </label>
            <input type = "number" id = "cno" required> <br> </br>

            <label for = "birthdate"> Birth Date : </label>
            <input type = "date" id = "bdate" required> <br> </br>

            <label for = "MailID"> Email : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "mail" required> <br> </br>

            <label for = "linkedin_link"> Linkedin Link : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Llink" required> <br> </br>

            <label for = "github_link"> github Link : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "glink" required> <br> </br>

            <label for = "picture"> Upload Picture : </label>
            <input type = "file" id = "Profile" >

            <br> <br>
            <center>
                <p> <strong> <h2> Education Details </h2> </strong> </p>
            </center>
            <br> <br>

            <label for = "secondry"> Secondry Grade : </label>
            <input type = "number" id = "sgrade">
            <label for = "syear"> Year </label>  
            <input type = "text" id = "syear" placeholder = "ex. 2007-08"> <br> </br>

            <label for = "Higher Secondry"> Higher Secondry Grade : </label>
            <input type = "number" id = "hgrade">
            <label for = "hyear"> Year </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "hyear" placeholder = "ex. 2009-10"> <br> </br>

            <label for = "b.tech grade"> B.Tech Grade : </label>
            <input type = "number" id = "bgrade">
            <label for = "byear"> Year </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "byear" placeholder = "ex. 2013-17"> <br> </br>

            <label for = "M.tech grade"> M.Tech Grade : </label>
            <input type = "number" id = "mgrade">
            <label for = "myear"> Year </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "myear" placeholder = "ex. 2013-17"> <br> </br>

            <br> <br>
            <center>
                <p> <strong>  <h2> Skill Set </h2> </strong> </p>
            </center>
            <br> <br>

            <label for = "operating sytem"> OS : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "os_names" placeholder = "ex. GNU/Linux, MacOS X, Windows 7/8/10"> <br><br> 

            <label for = "languages names"> Languages </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "languages_names" placeholder = "ex. C, C++, JAVA"> <br></br>

            <label for = "Slanguages names"> Scripting Languages </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Slanguages_name" placeholder = "ex. Python, Bash"> <br></br>

            <label for = "database names"> DBMS : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "database_names" > <br></br>

            <label for = "enlib"> Environments and Libraries </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "envi_names" > <br> </br>

            <label for = "web"> Web Technology : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "webtech_names"> <br> </br>

            <label for = "graphic"> Graphic : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "graphics_names" > <br> </br>

            <label for = "cloud tech"> Cloud Tech : </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "cloudtech_names"> <br> </br>

            <input type = "submit" name = "sub" value = "Submit"> <br> </br>

        </form>



    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> Note: You have to give each field a `name` attribute just like you've
>   given the `id` in order to be fetched from the next page.

^An Example:

```
<input type = "text" id = "fullname" name = "fullname" required autofocus>
```

Where I have added the `name = "fullname"` in the field type.

[PHP Manual: HTML Forms (GET and POST)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: Cant i do without php ? here is my code link http://ideone.com/m9TJDs

Comment: @BBD. Ahh, No, not without php. Check my edit in a second.

Comment: Ditto @HawasKaPujaari. From Me Too..

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Thank You . Got it !

Comment: [Yes, you can do it without PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893597/html-one-page-to-another-page#answer-32895203).

Comment: @DivineComedian Im sure he meant _HTML to HTML_ and nothing like PHP vs JS.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari *"Cant i do without php ?"*  I'm saying, "Yes, you can do it without PHP."

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [HTML form Tag- W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp), [Form Tag-PHP Net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) for more details

1) Through POST

**FirstPage.php**

```
<form method='POST' action='SecondPage.php'>
    <input type='text' name='EmailID'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**SecondPage.php**
(Through Name of input, we can access those values)

```
<?
$EmailEntered=$_POST['EmailID'];
?>

Email Entered Is : <?echo $EmailEntered;?>
```

2) Through GET

**FirstPage.php**

```
<form method='GET' action='SecondPage.php'>
    <input type='text' name='EmailID'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**SecondPage.php**
(Through Name of input, we can access those values)

```
<?
$EmailEntered=$_GET['EmailID'];
?>

Email Entered Is : <?echo $EmailEntered;?>
```

Comment: sounds good but php is necessary ? Cant do with just HTML ?

Comment: you have to access those variables in .php page @BBD.

Comment: @NanaPartykar On point brother `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to store the input in a database, you can do this without server-side processing.  Just use a form with its `method` set to `get` and a bit of JavaScript to get the query string variables on the page that the form's `action` attribute is set to.

[Here's a link to a CodePen I made](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyWKKY).  I made the form go to the same page and processed the variables there because I couldn't set up a separate page, but it's the same concept.

You could also use [local storage](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjewjp) if you need to store the input in the user's browser.

**HTML**

```
<!-- replace "#" with the page you want the form to submit to -->
<form action="#" method="get">
<label for="fullname">Full Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required autofocus>
<br />
<br />
<label for="contact_no"> Contact No. </label>
            <input type="number" id="cno" name="cno" required>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br />
<br />
<!-- this goes on the page you set the form's action to -->
<div id="output-name" data-variable="fullname">Full Name: </div>
<div id="output-cno" data-variable="cno">Contact No.: </div>
```

**JS**

```
// this is used on the page you set the form's action to
var outputFields = document.querySelectorAll('[data-variable]');

//loop through available output elements and add values to them
for (var i = 0, l = outputFields.length; i < l; i++) {
  var variableName = outputFields[i].getAttribute('data-variable');
  outputFields[i].innerHTML += getQueryVariable(variableName); 
}

//get the value of the specified variable from the query string
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return '';
}
```